# How run nodejs files to run phantomjs (Backbone snapshot for bots)

Tags: node.js, .htaccess, backbone.js, phantomjs

well....it's hard...I think the questions are easy, but the explanation is long ^^U

I have the directory for 'www':

```
myweb/symfony2 files
node/node installation
...
```

I install node with:

```
sudo apt-get install node npm
```

And, in node folder, i put:

```
npm install phantomjs
npm install express
```

And now....
Do not know what to do.

I have a website with RequireJS and Backbone.JS, and Google does not index anything of my web, because all the content is dynamic (i think, and i read), and had thought about installing nodejs + phantomjs to redirect bots to a 'static' version of my web create with phantom, with the code of this website:

```
http://backbonetutorials.com/seo-for-single-page-apps/
```

I do not know where to put the two files (web.js and phantom-server.js) that according to the website I need create.

Nor do I know the exact code to put to redirect by .htaccess to the same url, but with other port, because my urls are of the type:

```
example.com/stuffs
example.com/reviews
example.com/s/Name
example.com/u/user
etc ...
```

Comment: reinventing the wheel ? https://github.com/collectiveip/prerender

Comment: I thought I had been more or less clear that I have no idea what I'm doing, just reading the manual of the web i put, and assuming that I have to install Nodejs + Phantomjs as it is the only solution I found online, I'm not reinventing anything, I'm trying to do something and so far that was as clear as I found, because i don't found anything.

As for your url, looks interesting, but of course, i do not know where to put the files nodejs, much less i know how to use these things, i try to find a manual or something like that, thanks